# Strange wiring found in old bathroom

Tags: switch, light

I'm swapping out some old switches in my bathroom and have run into something I've never seen before.  The middle light switch here has both a black and red wire connected to the load terminal.

[image]

Currently the leftmost switch turns on the main lights, the middle switch turns on the shower light and fan, and the rightmost switch does nothing.  I'm assuming the previous owner must have wanted the shower light and fan to come on at the same time and changed the wiring.

Can I change this so the fan and shower light is controlled separately?  I'm obviously not an electrician but I want to do this safely and learn how to fix this myself in the future.

Comment: move red to the rightmost switch

Comment: @jsotola Just tried it, seems to be working!  I've always been wary of wiring, just wanted to make sure I'm doing everything correctly.  Thanks!

Comment: bottom screw on all three switches is connected to the same black wire ... so you cannot hurt anything by spitting one switch into two

Comment: It's likely that it was originally on 2 switches but moved to 1 switch to meet code.  I believe some areas require the shower light and fan to be on the same switch if there is no window in the bathroom.  Though I understand wanting to separate them, I don't want my fan running in the winter.

Comment: @rtaft Interesting!  I'm in Ontario, Canada but I don't have a copy of the code.  I suppose it's simple to put it back if it becomes an issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that the wiring is as you think it is, which you can verify by disconnecting one wire (red or black) at a time to see what the switch does, yes that is perfectly normal (provided the screw terminal can handle two wires, which may or may not be the case) and, yes, you can split.

Replace the single switch with a double [like this one](https://amzn.to/3yMH9N9):

[image: Leviton double switch]

A double switch will often have a removable tab on the "line" side so that you can have one hot in and two switched hots out without having to do anything special.

The other thing to do is make sure that both switched hots (red and black) and a matching neutral (white) are together in one cable/conduit. That is critical (for code and for safety), but sometimes things are not wired correctly.

Comment: Thank you!  Rather than use a double switch like this though, I'd just like to use the existing switch which does nothing.  All the neutral cables are connected together in the box.  Can I just move either the red or black load wire from the middle switch and connect it to the load on the third switch?  Again, thanks so much for your help.

Comment: Yes, you can do that, as long as the hot is paired with the same neutral as the other switch. If not, a little rewiring is needed but easy to do.